# Did the Electorate badge make a difference in question voting?

Tags: discussion, voting, data-dump, electorate-badge

## Yes.

[image: votes per question by week]

[Full Stack Overflow stats graphs for February dump.](http://hewgill.com/~greg/stackoverflow/stack_overflow/stats.html)

Comment: Are you counting downvotes?

Comment: Yes, that counts both upvotes and downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Skinner box FTW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operant_conditioning_chamber).

Comment: Glad to be a good rat in your experiment. :P Seriously, though, I have been upvoting more questions since I found out about this badge, so it's probably a good thing. +1

Comment: @Cha, I have almost stopped voting, as I only vote excellent or horrible questions, and I now don't want to vote answers because of this badge

Answer (score 2):

Your question is also an answer, and therefore isn't much of a question.

`<gaze at="navel">`On the other hand, what does that make this? ...`</gaze>`

EDIT: To make this less of what @random said, I will add that this experiment at least worked on the small scale on me. I've taken to upvoting more questions than I used to, which was almost none before, simply because I'd never thought of it. I'm quite a ways from getting the badge, but I figure as time passes my ratio will level out and it'll pop up randomly someday and make me feel good about myself.

Comment: It makes it a circle jerk!

Comment: "which was almost none before, simply because I'd never thought of it" that is the point of badges in a nutshell

Comment: That only works in hind-sight for us. We don't notice badges, don't go looking for them, and have no idea which ones we're near achieving. We do find it fun to see that we've been awarded one recently, but have never once made an effort to earn one and have never assigned any value to having them. We doubt that we're alone in this; however, the chart does suggest that there may be fewer of us than we previously assumed.

Answer (score -2):

I got the Electorate badge when it was released, so I don't have to change my attitude

Comment: Well bully for you!