# Prompt to specify downvote reason but allow to keep downvotes anonymous

Tags: feature-request, comments, down-votes

Recently @Catija replied to my answer ([If more users could vote, would they engage more? Testing 1 reputation voting on some sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393127/if-more-users-could-vote-would-they-engage-more-testing-1-reputation-voting-on/393275#393275)) about mandatory downvote reason (especially for 1+ rep users).

> “I'd be more open to a multi-select for low rep users that allows them
> to pick valid reasons to downvote without giving a free text field.”
> – [Catija Staff Mod](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393127/if-more-users-could-vote-would-they-engage-more-testing-1-reputation-voting-on/393275?noredirect=1#comment1315308_393275)

The proposal ( originally suggested in [John Saunders comment Jul 4, 2009](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment4016_2373) ) is to

- **add the quick list of reasons**, so the users don't even have to type.
- **Add an "anonymous" checkbox**, defaulting to checked.
- The dialog can be shown to any users (not only low rep).
- For those, who have enough reputation to add comments,  another option with free text  “your own comment” can be shown.
- If the user already added a comment or upvoted one of existing comments, dialog can be suppressed.

Two points suggested in the comments by Aaron Bertrand, Staff

- the proposal will be more valuable for answers, rather than for questions.
- the downvoter name if they chose to be anonymous will not be shown on the site, but (in particular for free text comment) should be recorded in the system to be available to moderators if there is an abuse.

I found a couple of suggestions that were deleted just because they were posted as answers instead of as a feature requests:

[Why isn't it required to provide comments/feedback for downvotes, and why are proposals suggesting this so negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-it-required-to-provide-comments-feedback-for-downvotes-and-why-are-pr/362930#362930) (the link may be not visible if you don’t have enough Stack Overflow reputation)

> Please include a reason for the downvote:
>
> - Too verbose
> - Argument is unclear
> - More research required
> - Issue not addressed
> - Duplication
> - Other
>
> Obviously there will be differences in popup layout & content for
> questions versus answers. **Closing the dialog without providing an
> option will be marked as *Other*.**

[Why isn't it required to provide comments/feedback for downvotes, and why are proposals suggesting this so negatively received?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-it-required-to-provide-comments-feedback-for-downvotes-and-why-are-pr/401916#401916) (the link may be not visible if you don’t have enough Stack Overflow reputation)

> - keep down/up votes anonymous
> - when you vote on a question or comment, a small popup opens, and you get to click on what applies to you (at least one choice). For
>   instance for an answer, it
>   is:
>
>   - technically wrong
>   - off topic
>   - not justified enough
>   - a repeat
>   - outdated
>   - incomprehensible
>   - ...?

I searched for similar questions and many of them were closed as a duplicate.
My suggestion is not a duplicate of [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes) that was completed in 2009, but a new **feature request** to improve the current implementation.

---

#### Some clarifications based on comments and answers feedback

The idea to [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes) is very popular (1245 votes). This suggestion is how to encourage them more with

- **less effort** (no need to type),
- allow to keep **anonymous** and
- allow even for those, who **don’t have enough rep** to post free text comments.

There are 246 questions linked to/from [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes). Many of them are closed as duplicates, but the big number is a clear indicator that the current system behaviour is not good and requires improvement(s).

The FAQ accepted answer [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are requests suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325416/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-requests-sugges) explains the reasons of the current implementation. However, most of points are not convincing and conclusions may be challenged. The current implementation may be redesigned to improve.

The difference with good  suggestion [Explaining downvotes, a new take on things](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353141/explaining-downvotes-a-new-take-on-things) is that proposed implementation is different. This request also intends to address the requirement to ask for downvote reasons for people with minimal reputation.

Some people think that knowing reasons for downvotes are useful only for the post author. Encouraging to explain downvotes is important to improve quality of posts, which will benefit the site in general. It also will benefit future readers who will see what is the problem with the post that downvotes thought about.

Comment: Doesn't matter if the comment will reveal the downvoter or not. I don't want to be forced to explain my downvote, plain and simple.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard  If you really don’t to explain( why not?) answer “other”

Comment: So it becomes extra step that I didn't ask for. Personally I do explain lots of times, but I don't want to be *forced* to do that. It will just have opposite effect on me. (make me less willing to explain.)

Comment: God, not another one of these. [You are not proposing any new ideas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325416/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-requests-sugges); please actually read the history of this idea before repeating it again.

Comment: @Nij looks like he did. I don't think it was asked before in this form, so it's legit and not duplicate. Most others are not direct feature requests and/or without explicit suggestions.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard, I’ve changed the title. You will not be forced, but prompted to make it easier to answer.

Comment: @nij, of coarse I read [why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-requests-sugges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325416/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-requests-sugges). Note the votes for the question:108  is greater than the accepted answer: 73. It means that the answer is not satisfactory, and the problem still exist and should be solved. If you don’t like my suggestion, suggest better

Comment: [Yeah, it has](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353141/explaining-downvotes-a-new-take-on-things). Nothing new here at all. @ShadowTheGPTWizard

Comment: You've read one post, great. There are another few hundred  to go. Start with putting *is:q explain downvotes* in the search bar.

Comment: @Nij, thanks for the link [explaining-downvotes-a-new-take-on-things ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353141/explaining-downvotes-a-new-take-on-things) to the good feature request. Indeed I didn’t find it before. However I’ve read quite a few of them (not hundred :) ). It just confirms that the problem exists and should be solved

Comment: If you think that downvoted questions confirm that a problem exists and should be solved (and earlier that highly upvoted questions answers suggest we don't find them satisfactory) then I really don't know what to say.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't believe that anonymous critical comments would have a positive effect.

Comment: @PM2Ring The idea to [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes) is very popular (1245 votes). My suggestion is how to encourage them more with less effort, allow to keep anonymous and allow even for those, who don’t have enough rep to post free text comments.

Comment: @RobertLongson If we assume that a hundred users created new requests 
 to improve encouraging to explain downvotes , but 20 active meta veterans
 with strong opinion that it’s not required,  downvoted each of them, the total vote  will be +80 for the change, even if each request has -20 votes  :).
Seriously speaking, question that is raised again and again highlights that it is a serious system problem and needs improvements.

Comment: I think at least for questions this would be more useful here on meta (where down-votes can be for very different reasons, e.g. this question is bad or unclear or lacks research vs. no I think this is a terrible idea or I agree it's a bug but don't agree developers should spend time on it). On the main sites I don't know that down-votes (again, for questions) often need further explanation. More often than not, questions are also eventually closed for the same reasons they are down-voted.

Comment: Now, for answers, I think there is more potential value there, because down-votes are often not visible (hidden behind +/-) while lacking the same type of inherent context (or companion close reasons) anyway. Future readers are here for answers, not for questions, and it can be very useful context for them to (a) know there are down-votes at all, and (b) have some general context about _why_.

Comment: Over the years, I've tried to be very good about giving that context to answer authors _first_, giving a chance to correct before I consider down-voting. But at times I've been very gun-shy about putting my name anywhere, since I've often at least had the _perception_ that I was being targeted after giving some helpful (and perhaps sometimes abrasive) context, whether I down-voted or not. Being able to anonymously comment (or pick an option) on answers might be a consideration, but it would have to be accountable (e.g. tied to you _in the system_ and available to moderators if there is abuse).

Comment: (That was _a lot_ of words to imply that it might be valuable to separate concerns and focus just on answers.)

Answer (score 12):

You've kind of missed the point, but don't worry, all the other people making this same suggestion have done so too.

Voting is mainly for those reading posts, not those asking or answering them. We want people to read clear and useful questions and then read their clear and useful answers and by corollary we want to lead people away from poor quality, bad or wrong answers. For that we don't really need comments at all. All you have to do is look at the overall score. If it's quite positive then that's likely to be a useful answer that will solve your problem, if it's negative then it probably isn't and you don't need to waste your time trying it.

So we need downvotes to distinguish answers that nobody's voted on at all from answers that people have analysed and actively determined aren't useful.

If voting gets the poster to improve their post then that's lovely too, but they are but one and the readers of posts are many. Optimising for a single individual is not the right way to go.

Comment: “ Voting is mainly for those reading posts” Exactly, as a reader I want to see in a comment, what was the reason why someone downvoted the post.

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim yet you're not interested why a solution has been upvoted? I find it odd that so many people apparently find no reason to know why something was considered good. Yet somehow feel the reason for downvote would help them.

Comment: @VLAZ, tell the truth, I didn’t think about reasons of upvoting before. Based on the number of votes for [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)  (1245 votes), many people are  more interested in  reasons of downvotes too.

Comment: Encouraging to explain downvotes is not “Optimising for a single individual”, it is important to improve quality of posts, which will benefit everyone on the site.

Answer (score 11):

This would introduce increased friction for casting downvotes. Yes, small yet one not present for upvotes.

Furthermore downvotes are already cast at a lot lower frequency than I feel they should be. Thus, I disagree that we should further discourage downvotes.

Comment: “ downvotes are already cast at a lot lower frequency than I feel they should be. ” Downvote penalty  stops some users (especially with low reputation) to downvote bad posts because they do not want to lost their 1 rep. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393127/if-more-users-could-vote-would-they-engage-more-testing-1-reputation-voting-on/393266?noredirect=1#comment1315386_393266

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim well that is a problem but it's not something you've focussed on with this question.

Comment: @RobertLongson, in a comment  I just explained why “downvotes are already cast at a lot lower frequency than I feel they should be. ”

Comment: Why not enough downvotes- see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398537/what-can-we-do-to-encourage-downvoting