# What is the correct way to reply to community wiki FAQ questions with an accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, tag-wiki

There is a FAQ community wiki question [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are requests suggesting such negatively received?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325416/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-requests-sugges) with the accepted answer, in which I disagree with most of the points.

Some arguments are already mentioned in the comments, but I want to add further considerations.

Is it ok to add my answer as new to the existing FAQ wiki question?
Or is it better to start a new discussion question?

Comment: The extended tag wiki for [tag:faq] has the following text: *please note that answers to these FAQ posts are meant as the current documentation as to how the system works or the established community consensus of community processes. If you have a suggestion on how to change it or disagree with the consensus, please post it as a new question or as an answer to an existing [tag:discussion].*

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog, thanks, can you make your comment as an answer?

Comment: A link to extended faq info is https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/faq/info

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag works is that questions first have to go through the stage of being tagged as [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed). Once we have a consensus answer as evidenced by an answer receiving a significant number of upvotes and we're sure the question should be a FAQ question (as evidenced by the question receiving upvotes and a moderator agreeing to retag the question) then the question may be changed to be tagged as [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) instead. Only moderators may add the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag to a question.

As the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) wiki says

> please note that answers to these FAQ posts are meant as the current documentation as to how the system works or the established community consensus of community processes. If you have a suggestion on how to change it or disagree with the consensus, please post it as a new question or as an answer to an existing [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion).

Other dissenting answers will be routinely deleted once the post is tagged as [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) because such dissent was given its chance while the question was in the (usually fairly long) [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) state.

For example for the question you've linked there are currently 7 deleted (and highly downvoted) dissenting answers.

Comment: Just a note, that dissenting answers with new reasons can be raised **after** the accepted answer become FAQ, and significant number of such answers is an indicator that it is not an absolute consensus. The big number of downvotes for each of the answers may be explained by opinion of relatively small  number of most active meta “veterans”  , that are happy with the current behavior and do not see the benefits to change it.https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393416/prompt-to-specify-downvote-reason-but-allow-to-keep-downvotes-anonymous?noredirect=1#comment1315798_393416

Comment: Not directly, as quoted they'd have to start as separate questions.

Comment: Is it correct that a new low-voted answer was added to a FAQ question https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/391622/163139 ?. Especially it is shown for me above the accepted and higher upvoted answer despite that my sort is Highest Score (default)

Comment: It's not a dissenting answer though is it?

Comment: but it doesn’t satisfy the requirement “ answers to these FAQ posts are meant as the current documentation as to how the system works or the established community consensus of community processes”.

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim feel free to downvote it if you think it's not useful. Or create another question suggesting that that answer be deleted.