# Novice questions approval queue

Tags: feature-request, review, vote-to-close, new-users

Close vote review queue [grows fast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151833/huge-close-votes-review-queue-on-stack-overflow)! Currently it has **101.7k** questions pending. My idea, based on a simple research from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151833/huge-close-votes-review-queue-on-stack-overflow/202442#202442) is to introduce another queue that will partially balance the close vote queue. It should work as follows:

- Questions from users with less than, let's say, 10 rep won't be shown immediately on the site. Instead they would go to a buffer, namely: Novice questions approval queue.
- This queue would be presented along with other queues on the [Review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review), and would be available for users with, let's say, at least 2000 rep.
- For each presented question, in most simple version, there would be two options: *Approve* and *Reject* (possibly also *Edit & Approve*).
- The new queue could of course offer some gamification infrastructure: small rep rewards for reviewing for users, lets say, under 3000 rep, and analogously to other queues: badges.
- If in the meantime OP would manage to earn enough rep, their question would get published automatically.

Roughly relating to [these statistics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151833/huge-close-votes-review-queue-on-stack-overflow/202442#202442) if we assume that all users that were to ask "good questions" (score 3 or more) would be completely discouraged by this policy and give up asking at all, we would lost `2%` of "good questions", while the *Close votes queue* length would be reduced by `23%`. What's more important, it seems that the queue would at least grow slower then now.

Differences from *First posts queue*:

- *First posts queue* handles both questions and answers. The latter do not seem a big problem on SO.
- This queue would somehow shield the page and close vote queue from very low quality questions.
- *First post queue* is based on the post being ... a first post :) This queue would work with regard to rep.

**EDIT**: In response to some points made in the comments&answers:

- This would not prevent people from posting completely. Earning 10 rep isn't much work, and would give them right to post without review.
- Any arguments in regard to gamification encouraging bad behaviour are not specific to this proposal - they describe valid problems, but in regard to the gamification idea in general.
- I think that this would introduce better behaviour of the queues (instead of one *Close votes queue*): for example it's very easy not to approve a question by a lazy programmer, who didn't even bother to spell correctly. Such easy to review questions are currently hidden in thousands of other, more complicated cases in the *Close votes queue*.
- two smaller problems are easier to handle than one big problem :)

Comment: The first post queue accomplishes the goals that this queue would, more or less, already.  It doesn't prevent the question from being seen, but it provides the opportunity for any needed moderation to take place, and the items in the queue tend to be handled quite quickly.

Comment: @Servy But the first post queue doesn't help at all with insanely fast growing close vote queue.

Comment: One of the nice things is you require no rep to ask a question or answer it. This changes that to be "you are free to ask questions if you have a minimum rep or if enough random people think it is acceptable".

Comment: @psubsee2003 The whole site's model is based on "what random people think" about your questions and answers :)

Comment: @BartoszKP as a collective, 5 or 10 is hardly a collection opinion.

Comment: Also, adding a rep award would absolutely destroy this queue. Look what little bronze, silver, and gold bits of pixels have done to the other review queues.  Users blindly click to get rewards and don't really care about the quality.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yet that's how all queues work.

Comment: @psubsee2003 That's the general problem with gamification, not specific to this proposal.

Comment: @BartoszKP right, but you are preventing someone from posting at all based on a small sample, not a collective opinion.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Well, not preventing entirely. Earning 10 rep is not much work, and would give you right to post also.

Comment: @BartoszKP It would be a heck of a lot more work if you make it really hard to post questions.

Comment: @Servy I agree - but isn't that what we expect from OPs? We expect that they are ready to give some effort when solving their problems. We don't like people who want to get the solution for free. Hopefully this would improve quality.

Comment: @BartoszKP You said that getting 10 rep is really easy, I was simply saying that that's going to be much less true if this change is made.  And while I do agree that asking good questions is hard and takes work, I don't see this as a good solution.  Users will just end up re-posting their questions as they don't get posted, they won't be exposed to lots of people for editing and comment feedback, and those they are exposed to are less likely to be active in the relevant tags, the feedback would be harder to see for the OP, the queue is open to abuse, and I don't see it reducing the workload.

Comment: @Servy I said that it "isn't much work", while it of course requires some work :) Comments could be enabled for reviers, feedback would be possible. As for your other objections - I get your point. I can't prove that the dynamics of increasing workload will get better, I just feel like it will (see my edit) :) It's in fact a divide-and-conquer approach - two smaller problems may be easier to handle, than one, currently big, problem.

Comment: This new queue will just get even bigger than the close votes queue and will make new users upset because their question *still* hasn't been approved.

Comment: @Servy "It would be a heck of a lot more work if [...]"  - while you say in [your other answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179761/231717) that 15 reputation limit is "extremely low". Make up your mind ;p

Comment: @BartoszKP I fail to see a contridiction.  15 rep is very low now.  It would not be low if users couldn't post their own questions easily.  Perhaps you didn't notice the "if" part of that quote.

Comment: @Servy They easily earn 15 posting question *if these questions get upvoted*. If they're get upvoted, then they're *probably* good (esp. if score is > 2). If they're good, then also with this mechanism they'd get approved. BTW: I'm not trying to reanimate this idea - mainly the "elitism" argument partially convinced me (partially, because inevitably there is elitism here) :)

Comment: @BartoszKP Clearly you don't understand much about the rep system here.  Even bad questions can easily earn 15 rep.  As for elitism; you're the one saying that new users shouldn't even be allowed to ask questions without the approval of established members; that's pretty elitist.

Comment: @Servy Let's skip ad personam shall we? If even a bad question can easily earn 15 rep, then also a bad question can easily get approved and earn 10 rep.

Comment: @BartoszKP First, if it would, then it would defeat the entire purpose of the feature request, to filter out bad questions, second many of the people who upvote bad questions are less likely to be the type of people to spend time in review queues (not that they don't, just less likely), so it would be quite a bit harder for users to get that early reputation.

Comment: @Servy The first concerns any human-based mechanism on this site, so it doesn't make sense in this particular case (you may have a point in that, this can be a sensible argument against complicating human-based mechanisms further). Second is a hazy psychological argumentation, thus weak. Even admitting, that yes, it would be a bit harder to post a question - that's the point, because allowing to post questions too easy leads to the garbage we currently have. Going back to "elitism" - that's why I've said, that the "elitism" argument convinced me (it's in the accepted answer).

Comment: @BartoszKP Your whole argument is that this will filter out lots of bad questions.  Now you're arguing those bad questions will just be approved.  If that's the case, why bother having an approval queue and wasting tons of people's time if we're just going to let all of the bad questions though.  As for the second, it's largely observational based on the existing very similar mechanisms, not just theorization.  And once again, you're the one here who's being elitist, saying that new users need to have their questions approved.

Comment: @Servy 1) You seem to forgot who brought up the "elitism" and in what context: I did, to say that I admit that more elitism can be bad, and that's what convinced me, that this idea might not be the best - hope it's clear now. 

2) I'm not arguing that those bad questions will just be approved. I was just pointing out that your argument that "sometimes bad questions get upvotes" is void, because also "sometimes bad questions could get approved". I'm arguing that these are equivalent flaws in both systems, creating questions that shouldn't exist and giving rep, so this is irrelevant.

Comment: @BartoszKP But it's not void.  You're trying to refute one problem with your proposal by saying that another *much bigger problem* makes it moot.  That may be true, but if it is, it's *much worse* for the sake of the proposal.  One of the two is certainly true.  Either bad questions get approved, and the feature serves no purpose, or they don't.  You don't get the best of both worlds.

Comment: @Servy First of all, I'm not really arguing about the proposal, but about your incoherent (IMHO) view on "how much minimum reputation" is hard or easy to earn. Secondly, "Either bad questions get approved..." - I really don't get this one - you don't have to prove that there can be mistakes in this process. There will be, as with any other process on this site. The fact that sometimes bad question would be approved doesn't make this proposal serving no purpose, just as the fact that sometimes bad questions get upvotes doesn't make the voting system purposeless.

Comment: @BartoszKP It's a question of degree.  Either most get filtered, or they don't.  Either way, one of the two problems applies.

Comment: @Servy If the close vote queue is working correctly (in terms of correctly closing questions) why wouldn't approval queue?

Comment: @BartoszKP Every queue out there except for the close vote queue has had *major* problems with reviewers not spending the required time and simply approving everything that passes through.  The close vote queue has had its own fair share of problems, but they are mitigated by the fact that 1) it takes 5 votes to close, not just a few as in the other queues, 2) there isn't an clear "approve" button to click through on 3) It has the highest minimum rep requirement.  That you're bringing this up would lead me to believe you don't have much experience dealing with review queues, or their problems.

Comment: @Servy 1) this can also take 5 votes to approve - irrelevant 2) fair point, still some (IMHO significant number) would get filtered - and this would reduce the *huge* close vote queue 3) this can also have highest minimum rep requirement - irrelevant. What you believe about my experience - irrelevant :)

Comment: @BartoszKP I fail to see how this is improving the workload.  For questions that would end up closed, you're spending just as much effort to not filter them as you would to close them after being asked, but you're adding a *ton* of work to approve every question that is already good, so in terms of reducing workload, you're not, you're increasing it, by a *LOT*.  You're also *dramatically* increasing the negative consequences of items not being reviewed quickly.  Not closing an old question ASAP is one thing, not showing people's problems right away is another.

Comment: @Servy Yes, this is another fair point. That's why I will point out again, that I'm not very fond of defending this proposal any more. I have another idea, but this time I'll try to think it through for a bit longer period, and check for duplicates more thoroughly ;) For now, let me just leave you with the problem "is 10 rep" easy or hard to earn to contemplate on ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have several problems with this issue, one will completely ruin this proposed review queue and make it completely worthless, and the other goes somewhat against what Stack Overflow is about.

> Questions from users with less than, let's say, 10 rep won't be shown immediately on the site. Instead they would go to a buffer, namely: Novice questions approval queue.

All fine and dandy, but Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange) is all about being an open site where anyone can ask a question or leave an answer without any rep.  Now you are putting a roadblock up to possible prevent users from doing that.

I certainly agree that 10 rep is a small amount, but I object to the notion that "as a new user, you can only post a question if a random sampling of 5 people who may or may not be qualified to judge your post think it is *acceptable*".  It just smacks of elitism.

And what about sites that still allow unregistered users?  This would effectively require them to have all of their questions "approved" before it would appear.

And when questions do get rejected, since they didn't get posted, how do you propose to provide feedback to the user?  Given what happens with closed questions getting reasked, I image that even more users will just keep reasking until there question makes it through (and given the state of reviewers and the review queues in general), you are going to end up with users who reask eventually getting their post through.

> The new queue could of course offer some gamification infrastructure: small rep rewards for reviewing for users, lets say, under 3000 rep, and analogously to other queues: badges.

Gamification will destory this queue.  I know you have said this is a problem with gamification itself and not this specific idea, but I disagree.  Any time any kind of gamification is added to the site, it causes problems.  Reviewers are falling over themselves to get hats, and before that it was little colored pixels (badges) that ruined the original review queues over 15 months ago, and we still haven't really fixed it completely (although it is better).  The moment you add rep to the game, you will literally render the queue worthless and cause more harm than good.  Instead of reviewers working in the best interest of the site to review posts and make objective decisions on quality, you will end up with a not insignificant percentage who review for speed and not accuracy/quality so they can review any many posts as possible and **game** as much rep as possible.

---

And let's not forget what Shog has mentioned several times recently.  The problem in the close vote queue is not new questions, i[t is the long tail of backlogged questions in specific tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208311/regarding-the-stack-overflow-close-review-queue).  So this does nothing to solve that immediate problem.

Comment: All right, you've convinced me. Thanks for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

First like Servy said we already have a queue for first posts and new users. It does *pretty much* the same thing.

Now about your comment :

> @Servy But the first post queue doesn't help at all with insanely fast growing close vote queue.

I don't think splitting the queue into two different queues really a solution. I mean, trading an insanely large queue for two very large queues isn't a solution.

Comment: Well yes, you got a point there that roughly speaking it's just splitting the queue into two queues. It's impossible however to predict how dynamics of these two queues will behave. So I say, let's give it a try. I think it will improve the quality of this site.

Comment: What do you mean by "Predict how they will behave". They are the same issue with different name no ?

Comment: Not exactly. Only a specific subset of questions would hit this novice queue, and I say it's a subset that's easier to review. Questions from "lazy programmers" for example are very easy to diagnose. They are in the close queue already of course, but hidden in thousands of other, more complicated cases.