# It's really hard to get started on Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request

I have been on Stack Overflow for some time.  It is an AMAZING resource and don't know if I would've got through the past 18 months without it.  I *love* it!  Problem is that I have "1" reputation.

All of my questions have already been asked and answered.

My "new user restrictions" mean:
- I can't vote up answers that were helpful.
- I can't comment on answers.

I sometimes have a question to ask one of the users that answered someone else's question but I can't.

This is hard!  How do I get a break?  Do I have to troll for a couple of days/weeks/months to answer enough questions in the hope someone votes some of them up just so I can do some basic functions?

Perhaps the number of site visits and length of membership could count for something?

Comment: Related: [why-cant-i-at-least-upvote-and-comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179758/why-cant-i-at-least-upvote-and-comment-on-correct-and-helpful-answers-without-f/179759#179759)

Comment: Post good quality questions and answers. You get upvotes and you get privileges.

Comment: submit good edits. You'll get 2 rep for each one.

Comment: Please link your account here to your account there.

Comment: @AlienArrays I read that as "all the questions I would have asked have already been asked and answered so I haven't asked them again"

Comment: Thank you to all who replied to this thread. I feel some of you may have missed my point-which is-I am new to Stack Overflow & it has been a tremendous resource. Many people have asked the very same question I was going to ask, and many generous people have adequately replied. Thus - my problems have been solved simply by reading older questions and their answers. I found it frustrating that I couldn't simply thank (up-vote) a very helpful answer without jumping through other "hoops "to get some points up. "Hoops" means asking-dummy-questions-to-get-answers-to-get-points. Thanks again to all!

Answer (score 5):

There are other ways to get reputation.

- Answer questions.
- Edit questions and answers to fix obvious problems. You'll get 2 points of reputation for each accepted edit. (There's an upper limit, however.)
- Become active on another site in the Stack Exchange network and get to 200 reputation. Then you'll get a bonus of 100 reputation on every other site in the network.

But I don't think getting extra privileges for being a member *without* contributing will ever be considered.

Comment: Also, the (relatively new?) [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) has a very clear, approachable description of how reputation works.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow even though you've been here for a while.

Have you thought about:

- answering questions? Each upvotes on answers will give you 10 reputation.
- Editing question / answers will give you 2 reputations if it is accepted.

It is not simply about asking question.. but when it comes to asking questions, no one has an edge. You can be new or Jon Skeet, you need to show proof of effort and show that you looked before answering. So being new isn't the problem, the fact that you ask duplicate *non-quality* (I'm implying here) questions is what is keeping you from getting started. I recommend you read the whole help section.

It is long but it will make your life around here **way** more easier.

Comment: "I recommend you read the whole help section." Which won't earn you any rep, but it will get you a nice shiney [badge](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed).

Answer (score 0):

If you had a question based on someone else's answer as you stated, then make that a real question.
Just make sure it's a specific programming question.